# Global Project Static Variables

Tags: c#, windows, static-libraries, system.drawing, gdi

I have three windows libraries that are for drawing different types of bitmaps. The one thing that they all share in common is the: Font, colors, and pens.

I would like to design a library that I could have all the standard fonts, colors, and pens so that if I make a font change it is changed globally across all the other libraries.

For example: I've got three libraries that draw onto bitmaps and they all use these same settings:

```
      internal static readonly Font ELEVATION_FONT = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 7.9f),
                                  DETAIL_BOX_FONT = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 8f, FontStyle.Regular);//"Palatino Linotype"

    internal static readonly Color BACK_COLOR_SCREEN = Color.Black,
                                   LINE_COLOR_SCREEN = Color.FromArgb(161, 161, 161),
                                   BACK_COLOR = Color.White,
                                   LINE_COLOR = Color.Black;
```

I would like to create one library called MySoluctionNameDrawing and all the other libraries that use these settings for drawing onto bitmaps they would use the ones from MySoluctionNameDrawing.

This is also for maintainability.

MySoluctionName is just the name of my solution, but I'm sure you get my point for demo purposes.

Anyone got any ideas as the easiest and cleanest way to have all my drawing related tools in one library and access them from other libraries with-out making a mess?

---

Here is what I've come up with.

Drawing DLL

```
namespace AlumCloudDrawing
    {

        public static class DrawingOptions
        {
            public static readonly Font ELEVATION_FONT = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 7.9f),
                                            DETAIL_BOX_FONT = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 8f, FontStyle.Regular);//"Palatino Linotype"      


            public static readonly Color BACK_COLOR_SCREEN = Color.Black,
                                                 LINE_COLOR_SCREEN = Color.FromArgb(161, 161, 161),
                                                 BACK_COLOR = Color.White,
                                                 LINE_COLOR = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

---

Usage ref from a Library that depends on the drawing dll library.

```
 internal static readonly Font ELEVATION_FONT = AlumCloudDrawing.DrawingOptions.ELEVATION_FONT,
                                  DETAIL_BOX_FONT = AlumCloudDrawing.DrawingOptions.DETAIL_BOX_FONT;

    internal static readonly Color BACK_COLOR_SCREEN = AlumCloudDrawing.DrawingOptions.BACK_COLOR_SCREEN,
                                   LINE_COLOR_SCREEN = AlumCloudDrawing.DrawingOptions.LINE_COLOR_SCREEN,
                                   BACK_COLOR = AlumCloudDrawing.DrawingOptions.BACK_COLOR,
                                   LINE_COLOR = AlumCloudDrawing.DrawingOptions.LINE_COLOR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually follow this pattern

```
/src
    FooApp.sln                       -- solution file
    /apps                            -- folder for apps
        /FooApp.Core                 -- core project
        /FooApp.Drawing1             -- project that references core
        /FooApp.Drawing2             -- project that references core    
    /tests                           -- tests
        /FooApp.Core.Test
        /FooApp.Drawing1.Test
        /FooApp.Drawing2.Test
```

Comment: So, I guess I'm just dreaming that I could have static constant in a library and reference that library from another and use the static constants as if they were local, with-out have to do Color color = MyConstants.BACK_COLOR

Comment: Why not? You just need to make sure the static variables are visible, i.e. change `internal` => `public`